# Which is it: "1½ years old" or "1½ year old"?

Tags: grammatical-number

1½ is not yet 2 or more, so which do we properly say: "1½ years old" or "1½ year old"?

Comment: Yet another numeric adjectival question. Yet another quantity-vs-quality question.

Comment: You can also say the child is **18 months old**. Alternatively,  **"He's one and a half"** would be understood perfectly (presumably one would already know the child's gender). I think the full written form is preferable, but there's no one to stop you from writing the number in digits: **"He's 1½ years old"** is also fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the entry is part of a classification:

> That kid is a *one-and-a-half-year-old*.

If the entry is describing the age of the person:

> That kid is *one and a half years old*.

Both of these work, and work similarly for whole numbers:

> That man is a *50-year-old* [person].
>
> That man is *50 years old*.

Comment: It would come much more naturally to a native speaker to say not "That man is a 50-year-old" *[note also the hyphenation here]* but "That is a 50-year-old man"; similarly, not "That kid is a one-and-a-half-year-old today" *[a construction I have* never *heard anyone use when referring to half years as part of someone's age]*, but "That is a one-and-a-half-year-old kid" (omitting the 'today'), or more likely, "That kid is one and a half years old". You would only include 'today' if today happened to be the child's half birthday.