# Is it One and half year or One and half years when used for work experience

Tags: grammatical-number

While writing a resume , I have come across this question while specifying work experience.

> Total Experience of One and Half Years

or

> Total Experience of One and Half Year

This may seem duplicate question , but I have read     [Which is it: "1½ years old" or "1½ year old"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/224884/which-is-it-1%c2%bd-years-old-or-1%c2%bd-year-old/224886#224886) but it was inconclusive when it came to time span referred for any activity.

Comment: It’s definitely never _one and half_, regardless of whether _year(s)_ is singular or plural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most idiomatic way to express this with "experience" would be:

> One and a half years' experience.

or, possibly

> A year and a half *of* experience.

Some people may well *say* "*a year and a halfs' experience*" but in writing it might cause as much debate as what we are having now and that isn't what you want people looking at your resume to do.